# Report by Device ID

Tags: square-connect

does anyone have a working example of getting the total sales for a location by device ID? I use the PHP v1 example at this time (as it lists the device ID and name), it works well for a general report but I have no way to filter a specific device ID or name.

This is the specific example: https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/blob/master/connect-examples/v1/php/payments-report.php

It works quite well but I've been unable to modify the logic to match a specific device name or device ID.

Answer (score 0):

In order to "filter" by a device you'll have to pull all your transactions out and then just look at the ones that were from the device you wanted. You could add some logic around line 100 to only add payments that come from a specific device.

Comment: Thanks! That is what I had tried but my attempt failed as I don't seem to be able to access the nested values during the loop they return undefined

Comment: We're they created on a physical device? Can you var dump and see the id? You might not be using the correct get methods.